# How to fix this method renaming problem with Java 8 ASM

Tags: java-8, rename, obfuscation, java-bytecode-asm

Recently I coded an Obfuscator with ASM in Java and wanted to rename classes, methods, and fields. But the problem is, that the code doesn't work it should too, and I have no clue how to fix that. The problem is, that if I obfuscate a jar every method in the class gets renamed, but sometimes (not every time) a bit of code is not getting renamed, so the jar can't be executed. E.g.

```java
public abstract class ColorThread implements Runnable
{

    @Getter
    private final String name;

    @Getter
    private Thread thread;

    public ColorThread(final String name) {
        this.name = name;

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(this::close));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        throw new NotOverriddenException("The Thread \"" + getName() + "\" is not overwritten.");
    }

    /**
     * This method interrupts the running thread.
     */
    public void close() {
        this.getThread().interrupt();
    }

    public void start() { //<- Method gets renamed e.g "⢍⢖⣕⠟⡨⠣"
        this.thread = new Thread(this, this.getName());
        thread.start();
    }

}
```

So this class got obfuscated but later in other code which calls:

```java
final ConnectThread connectThread = new ConnectThread();
connectThread.start(); // <- this line
```

the line with connectThread.start(); isn't renamed to "connectThread.⢍⢖⣕⠟⡨⠣();". If I use another class which extends ColorThread e.g. ReceiveThread, the start method gets renamed in this bit of code.

I struggled every time with this problem if I made an Obfuscator and because of it I ended the project. But now I want to ask here if someone can help me. Sorry for this long post, but I wanted to give everything needed to see the problem.

The Project is running on Java 1.8.0_161 with ASM-All as a dependency.

To read a jar i use this method. It will store all classes in an ArrayList:

```java
try (final JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(inputFile)) {
            final Enumeration<JarEntry> jarEntryEnumeration = jarFile.entries();

            while (jarEntryEnumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                final JarEntry jarEntry = jarEntryEnumeration.nextElement();

                if (jarEntry.isDirectory())
                    continue;

                final byte[] bytes = this.readInputStream(jarFile.getInputStream(jarEntry));

                if (jarEntry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                    if (jarEntry.getName().endsWith("module-info.class"))
                        continue;

                    final ClassNode classNode = new ClassNode();
                    //                  new ClassReader(bytes).accept(classNode, ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES | ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG);
                    new ClassReader(bytes).accept(classNode, ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);
                    this.classes.add(classNode);
                } else {
                    if (jarEntry.getName().contains("MANIFEST.MF"))
                        continue;

                    this.files.put(jarEntry.getName(), bytes);
                }
            }

            this.manifest = jarFile.getManifest();
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

After this i use my transformation system to rename the methods:

```java
@Override
    public void transform(final ArrayList<ClassNode> classes, final HashMap<String, byte[]> files) {
        final String mainClass = this.getJarResources().getManifest().getMainAttributes().getValue("Main-Class").replace(".", "/");

        final HashMap<String, String> methodNames = new HashMap<>();

        for (final ClassNode classNode : classes) {
            for (final Object methodObj : classNode.methods) {
                if (!(methodObj instanceof MethodNode))
                    continue;

                final MethodNode methodNode = (MethodNode) methodObj;
                if (methodNode.name.equals("<init>"))
                    continue;
                if (methodNode.name.equals(mainClass) || methodNode.name.equals("main"))
                    continue;

                methodNames.put(classNode.name + "." + methodNode.name + methodNode.desc, this.generateString(6));
            }
        }

        this.remapClasses(classes, methodNames);
    }
```

The remap method looks like this:

```java
public void remapClasses(final ArrayList<ClassNode> classes, final HashMap<String, String> remappedNames) {
        final SimpleRemapper simpleRemapper = new SimpleRemapper(remappedNames);

        for (int index = 0; index < classes.size(); index++) {
            final ClassNode realNode = classes.get(index);
            final ClassNode copyNode = new ClassNode();

            final ClassRemapper classRemapper = new ClassRemapper(copyNode, simpleRemapper);
            realNode.accept(classRemapper);

            classes.set(index, copyNode);
        }
    }
```

At the end i write the file:

```java
public void writeFile() {
        try (final JarOutputStream jarOutputStream = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(this.outputFile), this.manifest)) {
            for (final ClassNode classNode : this.classes) {
                final ClassWriter writer = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
                classNode.accept(writer);

                jarOutputStream.putNextEntry(new JarEntry(classNode.name + ".class"));
                jarOutputStream.write(writer.toByteArray());
                jarOutputStream.closeEntry();
            }

            for (final Map.Entry<String, byte[]> file : this.files.entrySet()) {
                final String filePath = file.getKey();

                if(filePath.endsWith(".kotlin_module") || filePath.contains("maven") || filePath.contains("3rd-party-licenses"))
                    continue;

                jarOutputStream.putNextEntry(new JarEntry(filePath));
                jarOutputStream.write(file.getValue());
                jarOutputStream.closeEntry();
            }
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you expect the invocation of `ConnectThread.start()` to get renamed, when you did rename `ColorThread.start()`?

Comment: The Superclass of ConnectThread is ColorThread, or did i something wrong by renaming the method of the abstract class (ColorThread)?

Comment: When the remapper looks at the code containing the invocation of `ConnectThread.start()`, it has no idea that the method will be inherited from `ColorThread`. There’s no maintenance of a type hierarchy tree. If you want that handled, you have to implement the handling.

Comment: Didn't really get it. So I need to create a hierachy tree to fix the issue?

Comment: You have to tell the `Remapper` that `ConnectThread.start()` should get mapped to the same name as `ColorThread.start()`. With the `SimpleRemapper`, you’d just have to add the entry to the map. However, a general Obfuscator has to come to this conclusion somehow, which implies processing the type hierarchy. For nontrivial input, you have to do that anyway, to detect which methods are overriding or implementing JRE/external library methods and therefore are exempted from renaming. That’s where the real challenges are. Consider unrelated `A.x()` & `C.x()` when `B extends A implements C` exists…

Comment: So at first thank you very much. I implemented a hierarchy tree and now it works. I'll edit the code later. 